# How to print the value of members of a structure with gdb debugger?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm using C.  How can I print the values of a member of an instance of a structure? Is it possible? At least is it possible in case of a structure declared as global variable (not a dynamically allocated one)?

Comment: What do you see if you say `p someStructVariable`?

Comment: say p1 is one instance of the structure, then something like "print p1->int_var" is something similar possiblle ?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `p p1.int_var`?  As far as I can remember, there is no arrow operator as far as gdb is concerned.  Just use the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set print objects on
p structVar
p *pointerToStructVar
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
p structVar.member
p pointerToStructVar->member
```

Comment: "set print objects on" is not useful for C++.

Comment: @Employed Russian: I disagree; it is exceedingly useful. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, a typo: "set print objects on" is not useful for C, only for C++. The original question is about C.

Comment: Actually comment below questionn by Jeff Mercado is the most apt answer :)